# Translating pseudocode into machine code

Tags: pseudocode, machine-code

For academic purposes, I am being asked to translate this statement

```
assign x the value 5
```

Into a machine code that is made up by an author of a computer science book, called brookshear machine code. I am given a hint that is

`(HINTS: Assume that the value of x is to be stored into main memory location 47. 
Your program would begin by loading a value into a register. You do not need to 
specify the memory locations of your program. Don't forget to end the program with 
the HALT instruction.)`

I am wondering if anyone knows the best way to approach this? He makes it clear to end with the halt instruction but I am unsure what exactly I should be doing.

0iii    - No-operation
1RXY    - Load register R with contents of location XY
2RXY    - Load register R with value XY
3RXY    - Store contents of register R at location XY
4iRS    - Move contents of register R to register S
5RST    - Add contents of registers S and T as binary numbers, place    result  in register R
6RST    - Add contents of registers S and T as floating-point numbers,  place result in register R
7RST    - OR together the contents of registers S and T , place result in   register R
8RST    - AND together the contents of registers S and T , place result in  register R
9RST    - XOR together the contents of registers S and T , place result in  register R
ARiZ    - Rotate the contents of register R one bit to the right, Z times
BRXY    - Jump to instruction at XY if contents of register R equal     contents of register 0
Ciii    - Halt
DRXY    - Jump to instruction at XY if contents of register R are greater   than contents of register 0
R,S,T - Register numbers
XY - A one-byte address or data value
Z - A half-byte value
i - Ignored when the instruction is de-coded: usually entered as 0

Above is the machine language I am expected to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only there were an instruction:

```
 EABXY - Store value XY at location AB
```

If that command existed, your program would be:

```
 E4705   # store '05' at address '47'
 C000    # halt
```

But, that instruction doesn't exist -- partly because it takes five half-byte characters, and the instructions are meant to fit into four.

So you're going to have to simulate the 'E' instruction using two steps.

You can't specify a value to put into an address directly.

- There is one instruction that lets you specify a value and put it somewhere.
- There is one instruction that copies a value from somewhere, into an address

That's *really* enough clues.

Comment: Thank you for responding, so I am still in "guessing" mode here because I dont understand how to break up "assign x" and "the value 5" into two 4 digit codes. I would say     
1R58 - 58 because 58 in hex is the letter X THEN
2558 - 2 because this is step 2 5 because i want 58 to go into register 5 THEN
c000

Comment: I would start with the op-code which would be 1 right? after that is where I get lost.

Comment: THANK you Slim. I will look this over and figure it out.

Comment: `1R05  
3R47  
C000`

Is what I got

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you

I am now being asked 
`assign halfway the value length + width`
Is there another way we can talk other than the comment box? I could really use your help if you are up for it =)

Comment: I think you need to take some time to think this through yourself.